# Does "to" always go after "listened"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

It's ok to write:

> The Queen listened to their pleas.

However, I am unsure if it's necessary to write 'to' after 'listened' if the sentence is inverted, for example, in a conditional. What is correct?

> If their pleas are listened to, they will...

or

> If their pleas are listened, they will...

Is there are rule to decide in cases like this?

Comment: To avoid the preposition at the end, you could also say: *If their please are **heard**, they will…* You often "hear" someone's pleas or cries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need the **to**.  The when *listen* is used with an object, it needs the preposition **to**, as "X **listen to** *noun*".  Even in a passive construction like *Y are listened to (by X)* it doesn't change.  Whether it is a conditional doesn't make any difference.